# How to measure performance of Android mobile web applications

Tags: android, performance, mobile, cordova

I'm new to android and I use PhoneGap to make mobile web application look like native Android application. So Normally tools like

- Pagespeed https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/
- https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

can be used to check performance of a web application. So I want to check performance after I wrap my web application with PhoneGap. I'm looking for a tool that measures performance of a Android mobile web application and gives me related graphs like above tools does. What can I use for that?

Answer (score 1):

as you know phonegap is a html based framework so yes you can test your htm-javascript code performance with all that tools but you cant measure your application performance with them, because phonegap performance depends on many factors(using plugins , ... ) but for my experience using less css will increase your performance enormously.

Comment: Thanks for the response Ocelot, I want to compare my application performance after doing some modifications to my app. If it is a pure web application I can measure them using above mentioned tools. But After wrapping it with phoneGap and install it in a mobile divise, I don't know a way to do that.